# How to search for a value in a MongoDB Database?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Is there a way to search for a value across multiple collections in a MongoDB Database.
Example:-
USA, Japan, UK 3 are my Mongo database.
In USA database I have collections Office 1, Office 2, Office 3, Office 4.
Similarly in Japan database I have collections Office 1, Office 2, Office 3, Office 4.
The same is in UK database.
***So now I have to run a search for a common index in collections in USA database. Is there a method to search entire database than searching a collection.***

Comment: Are they organized in a replica set or sharded cluster?

Comment: Hi @WernfriedDomscheit. Nothing of those sort just simple database with some collections.

Comment: You can combine the result from multiple collections using $unionWith aggregation stage that acts very simlar to UNION ALL in SQL databases

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo shell you can connect to remote MongoDB instances:

```
usaDB = Mongo("mongodb://username:password@us.database.net:27017").getDB("myDB");
usaDB.collection.find()
```

However, you cannot combine several databases in one query. You can do

```
data = usaDB.collection.find().toArray()
```

and then use `data` in your application.